# TeXnicCenter typing macros

Tags: texniccenter, xml, auto-completion

Sometimes my LaTeX document gets long and messy, and so it's hard for me to look through and find what I want. When I program, I usually have a macro in my IDE that creates a separator of comments to keep the code clean. I'm looking for something similar in TeXnicCenter. So it would insert the following

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Or something to that effect. Now if TeXnicCenter doesn't have the capability of making macros like this, is there a way I could take advantage of the autocomplete system to do this? So I would add a custom command to the TeXnicCenter LaTeX XML files so that it would autocomplete with the percent signs. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeXnicCenter allows for the creation of "user text modules" that are initiated via a shortcut. To insert your own module, follow `Insert`>`Own Text Modules`>`Manage Text Modules`. Now you can enter a new one called (say) `Separator`:

[image: Entering a new user text module in TeXnicCenter]

Once you've established the correct "before cursor" and "after cursor" combination, it is accessible via the menu selection:

[image: User text module accessible via menu]

Or via the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> (in my case).

Comment: Is there anyway to make this shortcut shorter and more intuitive?  Right now if I add another text module, I might need to reorder the modules and so change the shortcuts.

Comment: @JessRiedel: You could create your own hot keys via [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: When you create these modules, where are they saved?  How can I copy them to use on another computer or to share with someone else?

Comment: @A.Ellett: It's stored in the system registry. The TeXnicCenter source code - [`TextModules.cpp`](https://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/code/ci/default/tree/TeXnicCenter/TextModules.cpp#l188) - led me to that find. Here's a view of the `Separator` entry within the registry: [Registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WebhY.png). There doesn't seem to be an easy way to capture the content and port it to a new location.